# Why is my implementation of selectionSort faster than my implementation of bubbleSort?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, integer, selection-sort

I am trying to implement the selection sort algorithm in c. I don't know whether this is a correct implementation, and why my algorithm is much quicker than bubbles sort. Therefore, I am asking if you can tell me is correct or not and any improvement I have to make.

```c
main(){
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    system("color b");
    
    int A[NUM],i;
    
    for(i=0;i<NUM;i++){
        A[i] = rand()%30000;
    }
    
    displayArray(A);
    SelectionSort(A);   
    displayArray(A);
        
    system("pause");
}

void displayArray(int * A){
    
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<NUM;i++){
        printf("%6d ", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


void SelectionSort(int * A){
    
    int i,j,k, pos; 
    for(i=0;i<NUM;i++){
    
        k = A[i];
        for(j=i+1;j<NUM;j++){
            if(k >= A[j]){
                pos = j;
                k = A[j];
            }
        }
        A[pos] = A[i];
        A[i] = k;
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Seems to mostly have the correct structure, is the output as expected?

Comment: Probably belongs on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: `displayArray()` (and `SelectionSort()`) would usually take the size of the array as an argument rather than using a `define`d (or global) value... `void displayArray(int *A, size_t n);`

Comment: Replying to @mousetail, the output is as expected.

Comment: Replying to @L.Grozinger, thank you for suggesting me for the question-and-answer website -- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Replying to @Yunnosch, I doubt the program because when I compare to my bubble sort program, the selection sort program is way faster than bubbles sort. Yet, by the information from the web, the average, best and worst time of bubbles sort and selection sort are both O(n^2). What I interpret this result are bubbles and selection sort  sort in the same amount of time, but in reality isn't. That's the reason I doubt it.

Comment: That is interesting/helpful information, please [edit] it into the question.

Comment: However, if you implemented two sorting programs and one is surprisingly faster than the other (but correct in all tests) then I would doubt the other one....

Comment: Replying to @pmg, thank you for giving me a suggestion to improve my program. After I finish the sorting algorithm repertoire, then I will take the size of the array as an argument in order to make my sorting algorithm applicable.

Comment: According to [wikipedia article on sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) both *Bubble Sort* and *Selection Sort* have an average `O(n^2)` time complexity

Comment: Well, 99999 * 99999 in itself is 9.99*10^9, meaning integer overflow. However, if that happens depends on the value of `RAND_MAX`. Using `int` types is code smell no matter - you should be using `long long` and `99999ll` to be on the safe, portable side.

Comment: `O(n^2)` is asymptotic time complexity - do not take that to mean that two algorithms that are both `O(n^2)` will run in the same time on the same input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in this particular case your function is correct but in general there are at least three more or less serious drawbacks in the function.

The first one is that the function depends on the magic number `NUM`. So you can not use the function with any array with a different number of elements.

The second one is that you should not swap elements of the array with equal values. That is instead of this condition

```
if(k >= A[j]){
```

You should use the following condition

```
if(k > A[j]){
```

The third one is that you can not use the function to sort an array in the descending order or using some other criteria of sorting.

At least your function should not depend on a magic number.

For integer arrays I would declare and define the function the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void selection_sort( int a[], size_t n, int cmp( const void *, const void * ) )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        size_t pos = i;
        
        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
        {
            if ( cmp( a + j, a + pos ) < 0 )
            {
                pos = j;
            }
        }
        
        if ( pos != i )
        {
            int tmp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[pos];
            a[pos] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

int ascending_order( const void *p1, const void *p2 )
{
    int a = *( int * )p1;
    int b = *( int * )p2;
    
    return ( b < a ) - ( a < b );
}

int descending_order( const void *p1, const void *p2 )
{
    int a = *( int * )p1;
    int b = *( int * )p2;
    
    return ( a < b ) - ( b < a );
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 20 };
    int a[N];
    
    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = rand() % N;
    }
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    selection_sort( a, N, ascending_order );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    selection_sort( a, N, descending_order );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
2 10 1 2 14 8 0 17 13 11 5 12 9 3 13 13 3 12 4 1 
0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 8 9 10 11 12 12 13 13 13 14 17 
17 14 13 13 13 12 12 11 10 9 8 5 4 3 3 2 2 1 1 0
```

The function can be written in a more general form when it can be applied to an array of any type similarly to the standard C function `qsort`. But it is a more complicated task.

Answer (score 1):

You should check it with the output of `qsort()`.
Fill 2 arrays with this loop

```
int A[NUM], B[NUM], i, n;

for(i=0;i<NUM;i++){
    n = rand()%99999*rand()%99999;
    A[i] = B[i] = n;
}
```

Then define a compare function, like this:

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

And use it to call `qsort()` from the standard library and sort B

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void*))
```

The last step will be to compare A and B for a good number of random generated arrays.
If they're equal, your implementation works.
Of course this is not mathematical proof, but if you're working on Selection sort, you'll be fine with empirical testing

Answer (score 0):

As L.Grozinger already [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66133572/is-my-code-correct-and-what-improvements-can-i-make#comment116927343_66133572), two algorithms having the same complexity does not mean that they will be equally fast. It only means that if you scale the input by some factor, the running time of both algorithms will increase by the same proportion.

For example, suppose that you first run both bubbleSort and selectionSort on an input of 100 elements. You might, for example, find that bubbleSort takes 4 milliseconds while selectionSort needs only 3 milliseconds. If you now scale the input by a factor two, i.e., to 200 elements, you'll find that both algorithms take about four times as long: the running time of bubbleSort jumps from 4 ms to 16 ms, while the running time of selectionSort jumps from 3 to 12 ms.

BubbleSort is actually known to be slower than selectionSort. To see why this is the case, consider that comparison sorting algorithms (a family that bubbleSort and selectionSort are both members of) need to do two kinds of things: comparing and swapping. Both algorithms need to perform O(N^2) comparisons in order to sort a list, which is why both have an overall complexity of O(N^2). But selectionSort needs only O(N) swaps, where bubbleSort needs O(N^2) swaps. The big O notation normally hides this fact, because it abstracts away details about particular operations.

A similar thing is going on with quickSort and heapSort. They are both O(n log n), but heapSort makes way more cache misses than quickSort. That's why quickSort is much, ahem, *quicker*.

BubbleSort serves only an educational purpose; it is in all respects worse than both insertionSort and selectionSort. In fact, this is the reason why it serves an educational purpose.

Comment: Does @Julian mean "are both members of  _comparison sort_  " in the 3rd paragraph?

Comment: Yes, bubbleSort and selectionSort are both members of (the family of (comparison sorting algorithms)).